# TensorFlow: Visualizing Custom Layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorboard

I'm implementing a paper where I have to write custom layer. Following is the code.

```
class CouplingLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    """
    Additive Coupling Layers in NICE model

    Parameters
    ----------
    m_layers: list of number of neurons in MLP
    pos: position where mask is not placed (0 is for X, 1 is for X2)

    """
    def __init__(self, m_layers, pos):
        super(CouplingLayer, self).__init__()
        self.m = MLP(m_layers)
        self.pos = pos

    def forward(self, H1, H2):
        """
        Forward pass in the network

        Parameters
        ----------
        H: Input signal

        Returns
        -------
        Z: latent variable

        """
        Z1 = H1 + (1 - self.pos) * self.m.forward(H2)
        Z2 = H2 + self.pos * self.m.forward(H1) 
        return Z1, Z2
```

I have further created a network by stacking these layers.

Question: Is there a way to visualize the structure of the graph? If so, then how can I do it for the code provided above?

I can use `tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model)` but this does not give me the internals of the model.

Comment: You can use Tensorboard to view the model graph. Tensorboard provides conceptual graph view and op-level graph. For more details about library find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/graphs). Thanks